# Riot API - How can I have summoners roles on a current game

Tags: riot-games-api

I'm currently developing a live game analysis system similar to op.gg, u.gg or porofessor.gg and I'm not able to get the summoners roles (individualPosition) with the SUMMONER_V4 endpoint. This infos can be retrieved from MATCH_V4 and MATCH_V5 but not in current game only on post games.

Do you have a solution ?

1 summoner from SUMMONER_V4

```json
{
            "teamId": 100,
            "spell1Id": 4,
            "spell2Id": 12,
            "championId": 134,
            "profileIconId": 29,
            "summonerName": "ZWYRØØ",
            "bot": false,
            "summonerId": "AMNq5HI58rERnuyXFIG59jefC50DedqayUTkovUa2Vyf4yc",
            "gameCustomizationObjects": [],
            "perks": {
                "perkIds": [
                    8112,
                    8139,
                    8138,
                    8135,
                    8232,
                    8226,
                    5005,
                    5008,
                    5003
                ],
                "perkStyle": 8100,
                "perkSubStyle": 8200
            }
        }
```

1 summoner from MATCH_V5

```json
{
                "assists": 11,
                "baronKills": 0,
                "bountyLevel": 4,
                "champExperience": 16132,
                "champLevel": 16,
                "championId": 92,
                "championName": "Riven",
                "championTransform": 0,
                "consumablesPurchased": 7,
                "damageDealtToBuildings": 4623,
                "damageDealtToObjectives": 6137,
                "damageDealtToTurrets": 4623,
                "damageSelfMitigated": 29549,
                "deaths": 5,
                "detectorWardsPlaced": 3,
                "doubleKills": 3,
                "dragonKills": 0,
                "firstBloodAssist": false,
                "firstBloodKill": true,
                "firstTowerAssist": false,
                "firstTowerKill": false,
                "gameEndedInEarlySurrender": false,
                "gameEndedInSurrender": false,
                "goldEarned": 14587,
                "goldSpent": 14205,
                "individualPosition": "TOP",
                "inhibitorKills": 1,
                "inhibitorTakedowns": 1,
                "inhibitorsLost": 0,
                "item0": 6630,
                "item1": 2055,
                "item2": 6035,
                "item3": 3071,
                "item4": 3044,
                "item5": 3158,
                "item6": 3364,
                "itemsPurchased": 27,
                "killingSprees": 4,
                "kills": 15,
                "lane": "TOP",
                "largestCriticalStrike": 0,
                "largestKillingSpree": 4,
                "largestMultiKill": 3,
                "longestTimeSpentLiving": 487,
                "magicDamageDealt": 0,
                "magicDamageDealtToChampions": 0,
                "magicDamageTaken": 9753,
                "neutralMinionsKilled": 9,
                "nexusKills": 1,
                "nexusLost": 0,
                "nexusTakedowns": 1,
                "objectivesStolen": 0,
                "objectivesStolenAssists": 0,
                "participantId": 1,
                "pentaKills": 0,
                "perks": {
                    "statPerks": {
                        "defense": 5002,
                        "flex": 5008,
                        "offense": 5008
                    },
                    "styles": [
                        {
                            "description": "primaryStyle",
                            "selections": [
                                {
                                    "perk": 8010,
                                    "var1": 720,
                                    "var2": 0,
                                    "var3": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "perk": 9111,
                                    "var1": 2616,
                                    "var2": 520,
                                    "var3": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "perk": 9104,
                                    "var1": 12,
                                    "var2": 30,
                                    "var3": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "perk": 8299,
                                    "var1": 1072,
                                    "var2": 0,
                                    "var3": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "style": 8000
                        },
                        {
                            "description": "subStyle",
                            "selections": [
                                {
                                    "perk": 8236,
                                    "var1": 14,
                                    "var2": 0,
                                    "var3": 0
                                },
                                {
                                    "perk": 8210,
                                    "var1": 15,
                                    "var2": 0,
                                    "var3": 0
                                }
                            ],
                            "style": 8200
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "physicalDamageDealt": 122017,
                "physicalDamageDealtToChampions": 27842,
                "physicalDamageTaken": 17221,
                "profileIcon": 4982,
                "puuid": "ntuHEb-brsQY_ecD0_RJWuM7aksXwMdaK2q16TQ3vvJ_F11cOUtg_kwhGQ-Ihn4wDSu7WPuQipJn3Q",
                "quadraKills": 0,
                "riotIdName": "",
                "riotIdTagline": "",
                "role": "DUO",
                "sightWardsBoughtInGame": 0,
                "spell1Casts": 397,
                "spell2Casts": 71,
                "spell3Casts": 142,
                "spell4Casts": 34,
                "summoner1Casts": 4,
                "summoner1Id": 4,
                "summoner2Casts": 7,
                "summoner2Id": 14,
                "summonerId": "ZVUXWayHZDCDR5V67fUp14i3vsZNMmqIjmppq2XJepptJ7Y-",
                "summonerLevel": 40,
                "summonerName": "ojdfviys",
                "teamEarlySurrendered": false,
                "teamId": 100,
                "teamPosition": "TOP",
                "timeCCingOthers": 35,
                "timePlayed": 1719,
                "totalDamageDealt": 123497,
                "totalDamageDealtToChampions": 29232,
                "totalDamageShieldedOnTeammates": 0,
                "totalDamageTaken": 28681,
                "totalHeal": 6272,
                "totalHealsOnTeammates": 0,
                "totalMinionsKilled": 160,
                "totalTimeCCDealt": 107,
                "totalTimeSpentDead": 183,
                "totalUnitsHealed": 1,
                "tripleKills": 1,
                "trueDamageDealt": 1480,
                "trueDamageDealtToChampions": 1390,
                "trueDamageTaken": 1706,
                "turretKills": 2,
                "turretTakedowns": 4,
                "turretsLost": 5,
                "unrealKills": 0,
                "visionScore": 22,
                "visionWardsBoughtInGame": 5,
                "wardsKilled": 2,
                "wardsPlaced": 6,
                "win": true
            }
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: you can create your own array or json with current game and all further informations you want to add it ?

Comment: The informations are not in the json it's very specifique to this api we advice me to use this project : https://github.com/Canisback/roleML